# What is wrong with my fantail goldfish - Red Spot on Bum

Tags: fish, aquarium

I have a fantail fish which has a small red spot on his/her bum, and I have noticed one of the other fish has been chasing it. I have had the fish together for many years now & do regular 10% water changes. What could this be?

I have two goldfish, one fantail and three very small minos in a tank size 15 inches High - 22 inches L (Across the front) - 11 inches Wide (Side).

Thank You.

Comment: Does it have any of the other symptoms described [here](http://www.tetra-fish.com/aquarium-information/aquarium-fish-diseases-how-to-spot-them.aspx)?

Comment: Can you post a picture of it?